# Remove first comma from a comma separated list in Python

Tags: python, list, set

I have code that computes a Fibonacci sequence from the first 2 inputs from a user. Then it will accept and compare the subsequent entries if they belong to the sequence earlier computed. Then it will return a list and count of those values. My issue is that when I print, there is an unwanted comma at the start of the printed list. My code below:

```py
# Taking the first 2 inputs and computing of sequence
a = int(input("Please enter a"))
b = int(input("Please enter b"))

num1, num2 = a, b
fibo = []
for i in range(1, 15):
    numn = num1+num2
    num1 = num2
    num2 = numn
    fibo.append(num1)


# Taking subsequent user inputs and comparing with the above sequence list
val = []
inpt = None
count = 0
common = []
while inpt != 0:
    inpt = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    val.append(inpt)

if val[0] == 0:
    print('Zero alone will not do')
else:
    for j in val:
        if j in fibo:
            common.append(j)
    if len(common) == 0:
        print('No fibonacci values found')
    else:
        # Putting common values in a set to keep only unique ones
        unique = set(sorted(common))
        num_common = len(unique)

# Print a list of unique matching values and their count
print(str(num_common)+' matching values:', *unique, sep=",")
```

The output is something like this below, assuming a,b=0,1.

3 matching values:, 2, 3, 5

I want output like below - with just a space and not a comma at the beginning:

3 matching values: 2, 3, 5

Comment: As an aside, this question could be simplified greatly. The steps to create `unique` aren't part of the problem. You could reproduce with `unique = [1, 2, 3]`, then the print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the sep applies between all the arguments to print, so either combine the values before passing them to print using join:

```
print(str(num_common)+' matching values:',','.join(str(i) for i in unique))
```

Or make two print calls.

```
print(num_common, 'matching values:', end='')
print(*unique, sep=',')
```

I'd tend to use f'' string interpolation, mostly as use Python for web services so rarely have to print a formatted result, but usually have to pass it to something else, and string interpolation works wherever you need it to but the various print arguments are specific to print only:

```
print(f'{num_common} matching values: {", ".join(str(i) for i in unique)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `join()` instead of `sep`:

```py
print(str(num_common) + ' matching values: ' + ', '.join(map(str, unique)))
```

Comment: Thanks all. Solved and learnt a bunch. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem `print(str(num_common)+' matching values:',*unique,sep=",")` , sep argument from print will use its value to separate the unnamed arguments passed to the print function call. Rather than using sep, you can use the string method `join`, it accepts an list of **strings** and uses the string which it was called on, to concatenate the values. Since you have an array of ints, you can do it like that:

```py
values_concatenated = ", ".join(map(str, unique))
print(str(num_common) + ' matching values: ' + values_concatenated)
```